# Linux: How to get path to file in nested folder

Tags: java, linux

I want to execute:

```
java -jar rootfolder/nested folders/*.jar
```

I just don't know how to specify the nested folder structure, which I will not know as it is dynamically generated.

I tried:

```
java -jar rootfolder/**/*.jar
```

but get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Any example of expected results? "How to get path to file in nested folder" is not clear, which file do you have in mind? What if there are many files with `jar` extension in that nested folders, how should this command work?

Comment: The first jar found should be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you find the jar-file, using a `find` command?

```
find ./ -name "*.jar"
```

In case yes, you can use the result of that command as input for your command:

```
java -jar `find ./ -name "*.jar"`
```

Or, (this is more readable but it does not always work):

```
java -jar $(find ./ -name "*.jar")
```

Comment: **find** has the neat *exec* parameter: `find . -name *.jar -exec java -jar '{}' \; -quit` (*-quit* stops after first match)

Answer (score 1):

This should run the first .jar file found:

```
java -jar `ls rootfolder/**/*.jar | head -1`
```